# Get column from another map type column spark scala dataframe

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

I have a dataframe having 1 column as a case class format like this

```
case class FeaturizedDataset(
    indices: Array[String],
    values: Array[Float]
)
```

The table is something like this

```sql
|sourceId|scoreMapping           |
|--------|-----------------------|
|3       |{[1,3,4],[0.1,0.2,0.3]}|
|4       |{[1,3,4],[0.1,0.2,0.3]}|
|1       |{[1,3,4],[0.1,0.2,0.3]}|
|4       |{[1,3,4],[0.1,0.2,0.3]}|
```

I would like to get the score corresponding the score ID in scala. How can I do this?

For e.g., if `sourceId = 3` => `score = 0.2`, if `sourceId = 1` => `score =0.1` ...

Answer (score 0):

Using `arrays_zip` + `filter` functions:

```
val df1 = df.withColumn(
  "tmp",
  arrays_zip(col("scoreMapping.indices"), col("scoreMapping.values"))
).withColumn(
  "score",
  filter(col("tmp"), x => x("0") === col("sourceId"))(0)("1")
).drop("tmp")
```

You zip `scoreMapping` indices and values then filtering where indices is equal to `sourceId`.